# When I hit a breakpoint WebStorm opens a new read-only version of the file in Vagrant

Tags: javascript, node.js, vagrant, webstorm

I have recently setup Vagrant with WebStorm IDE and the app is running well but when debugging or putting a breakpoint on a code line, a new read-only version of the same file opens instead of hitting where breakpoint is put.

Any help, dear members ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to [WEB-34370](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-34370), please follow this ticket for updates